# Error in alfresco bpm activiti: "bpm_assignees" is not defined

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I have the next error when I try to execute an activii workflow:

> org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 02190005 Failed to execute
>   supplied script: 02190004 ReferenceError: "bpm_assignees" is not
>   defined. (AlfrescoJS#3)

In my process I don´t use that variable.  I'm using bpm_group_assignee, no bmp_assignees, so I don't understand why.

Comment: Add bpmn file.. or the script where it is getting failed.

Comment: Hi, @KrutikJayswal, these  are the files I changed:   BPMN ->  https://paste.ofcode.org/ySTbyD4j98xyMtVET7aMSM
 share-config-custom.xml ->  https://paste.ofcode.org/X3bCdgrFEHMnXWafPerN8d
  myWorkflowModel.xml ->  https://paste.ofcode.org/36B38vcei2pAH3nkFLT96RW

Comment: @JoséManuelDénizRivero the links you provided gives 404. please paste your code in you question